# Can't See Color in Shading Viewport

Tags: texturing, shaders, color

When I go to the shading viewport, my objects are 2D grey (not white) even though the 'material viewport' tab is auto selected. Downloading the same Blender file, to another computer it works fine. My computer's specs are adequate and the drivers updated. Anybody have an idea what's up? thanks[image]

Comment: Hello maybe it's a driver problem, what does it give if you come back to a previous one?

Comment: Hi @moonboots - sorry, not sure what you mean. Do you mean to try using a previous driver?

Comment: Yes that's it...........

Comment: Thanks - Actually I found someone with same problem in a three year old thread and using an earlier version of the driver was a fix for them so fingers crossed, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @moonboots - SUCCESS! I rolled back the drivers and all good - THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Going to device manager, display adaptors, drivers, and clicking the option to 'roll back' the drivers to previous versions solved this problem. thank you @moonboots